# How can I correctly set the current date in this specific format into this insert query on an Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have to implement an insert this insert query on an **Oracle** db:

```
insert into CODA_RX (PK_CODA, FK_TIPO_DOC, FK_PIVA_DESTINATARIO, DATA_IN, FK_STATO, DATA_OUT, CANALE, SIZE_XML, FK_PIVA_MITTENTE) 
       values(70030, 5, 06655971007, '06-MAG-15', 2, '06-MAG-15', 'WEB', 553, 01392380547);
```

As you can see there are 2 **DATE** fields named **DATA_IN** and **DATA_OUT**. In the previous version of my query the date value is explicitly written (it is fixed: '06-MAG-15').

How can I use the current date in this specific format **'06-MAG-15'** (DD-MM-YY)?

Tnx

Comment: What datatype is DATA_IN and DATA_OUT?

Comment: @Boneist oh yes, I didn't noticed that. I'll take my comment back.

Answer (score 4):

`'06-MAG-15'` is NOT a **DATE**, it is a **STRING**.

- Use **TO_DATE** with proper format model to convert a string into date.
- Also, it is better to avoid **NLS dependency**.
- Another thing, avoid 2 digit values for **YEAR**. Don't reinvent the **Y2K bug**. Or, use the  `RR` format. But, there are some rules you must know. I prefer `YYYY`.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('06-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE('
---------
06-MAY-15

SQL>
```

> How can I correctly set the current date in this specific format into this insert query on an Oracle DB?

This is completely different from what you have explained in the question.

Remember, **DATE** doesn't have any **format**. What you see is for **display** so that we could interpret it easily. *Oracle stores DATE in a proprietary format internally in `7 bytes`.*

If you want to insert current date, then there is no need of any literal and format. Use **SYSDATE**.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
05/21/2015 15:15:05

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `TO_DATE()` in order to convert a string into a DATE datatype. eg:

`TO_DATE('06-MAY-2015', 'dd-MON-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')`

See [the documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm) for more information on `TO_DATE()`, and a list of format masks can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Conversely, if you want to display something that's a DATE datatype in a particular format, you can use `TO_CHAR()` with the appropriate format mask.