# Why this simple insert query can't work?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not so into database and I have some problem implementing a simple insert query (on an **Oracle** db) in a table named **CODA_TX** that have the following structure:

```
describe CODA_TX
Nome                 Nullo    Tipo           
-------------------- -------- -------------- 
PK_CODA              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
FK_TIPO_DOC                   NUMBER(4)      
FK_PIVA_MITTENTE              VARCHAR2(16)   
FK_CDZZ                       VARCHAR2(4)    
DATA_IN                       DATE           
FK_STATO             NOT NULL NUMBER(2)      
DATA_OUT                      DATE           
NUM_DOC                       VARCHAR2(35)   
CANALE                        VARCHAR2(3)    
SIZE_XML                      NUMBER(10)     
FK_PIVA_DESTINATARIO          VARCHAR2(20)   
INDIRIZZAMENTO                VARCHAR2(100)  
SIGNATURE                     VARCHAR2(1)    
PRG_CONSERVAZIONE             NUMBER(10)     
MIT_DATA_CONS                 DATE           
MIT_LOTTO_CONS                VARCHAR2(50)   
DES_DATA_CONS                 DATE           
DES_LOTTO_CONS                VARCHAR2(50)   
SEGNALAZIONE                  VARCHAR2(4000) 
IDOC_NUM                      NUMBER         
CODICE_UFFICIO_PA             VARCHAR2(6)    
IDENTIFICATIVO_SDI            NUMBER(12)     
NOME_FILE_SDI                 VARCHAR2(50)
```

So I have implemented this insert query to create a new record. As you can see I specify some field that have to be valorized, the not specified I think that should automatically setted to **null** (is it correct?):

```
insert into 
  CODA_TX (PK_CODA, 
           FK_TIPO_DOC, 
           FK_PIVA_DESTINATARIO, 
           DATA_IN, 
           FK_STATO, 
           DATA_OUT, 
           CANALE, 
           SIZE_XML, 
           FK_PIVA_MITTENTE) 
   values(70045, 
           5, 
           01392380547, 
           Thu May 21 16:33:40 CEST 2015, 
           2, 
          Thu May 21 16:33:40 CEST 2015, 
           WEB, 
           554, 
           01392380547)
```

The problem is that performing this query I obtain this error message:

```
Bind variable "33" non dichiarata (NOT DECLARED)
0 righe inserito.
```

What it exactly means? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: you know that text values should be enclosed into single quotes `'`, right?

Comment: Enclose strings in single quotes, and convert date-time strings to date values (using `to_date`)

Comment: You need to encase strings in quotes, and dates need to be formatted according to your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting, or using to_date function to format as you wish.

Comment: Please read the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL" in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00217

Comment: The most important problem is that, your values doesn't match with the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thu May 21 16:33:40 CEST 2015

That is neither **string** nor **date**.

Your **DATA_IN** and **DATA_OUT** column data types are DATE, and date cannot have timezone.

- Add single quotation marks to first make it a literal.
- Use **TO_DATE** with proper **FORMAT MODEL** to convert the literal into date.
- Remove the timezone element, or first change the data type of your column to **TIMESTAMP**.

Seems like you did not put any effort to research and understand anything from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30369930/3989608) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369585/how-can-i-correctly-set-the-current-date-in-this-specific-format-into-this-inser).

> WEB

You must always enclose the **string values** within **single-quotation marks**.

For example,

```
'WEB'
```

> 01392380547

**NUMBER** cannot start with zero. Since you declared it as **VARCHAR2** data type, enclose it within **single-quotation marks**

The most important problem is that, **your values doesn't match with the columns**. For example, the third last value `Thu May 21 16:33:40 CEST 2015` is mapped to column `CANALE`. However, the column is described as:

> CANALE                        VARCHAR2(3)

So, you have *basic problems* with your *simple insert query*.

Comment: He should also enclose `WEB` into single quotes.

Comment: @Zenadix Yes, and I updated my answer. There are two more string values missing single quotes.